# Does Dependent Care FSA/DCAP have an income phaseout?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, dcfsa

In the past, dependent care expenses could be deducted through either a Dependent Care FSA/DCAP (an employer program) or a Dependent Care Tax Credit (aka Form 2441). On the surface, they seem like two ways to accomplish the same thing, except that the FSA/DCAP is a lot more work to execute. However, in 2021, I found that the Dependent Care Tax Credit has an income phaseout. On Form 2441 line 8, it says:

> If line 7 is over 438,000, don't complete line 8. Enter zero on line 9a.

Is the Dependent Care FSA/DCAP a better option in this situation?